# Конструктор порожденных объектов от фабрики

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Подскажите как из конструктора factory передать значения в порожденные объекты, либо при создании нового инстанса можно было забивать значения в конструктор, Чет совсем запутался

```
class carFactory {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public static function build ($type = '') {

        if($type == '') {
            throw new Exception('Invalid Car Type.');
        } else {
            $className = 'car_'.ucfirst($type);
            if(class_exists($className)) {
                return new $className();
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Car type not found.');
            }
        }
    }
}

class car_Sedan {

    public function __construct() {
        echo "Creating Sedan";
    }
}
class car_Suv {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Creating SUV";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
<?php
class carFactory {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public static function build ($type = '', $options = []) {

        if($type == '') {
            throw new Exception('Invalid Car Type.');
        } else {
            $className = 'car_'.ucfirst($type);
            if(class_exists($className)) {
                return new $className($options);
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Car type not found.');
            }
        }
    }
}

class Car
{
    public function __construct($options = [])
    {
        var_dump($options);
    }
}

class car_Sedan extends Car {

    public function __construct($options) {
        parent::__construct($options);
        echo "Creating Sedan";
    }
}
class car_Suv extends Car {
    public function __construct($options) {
        parent::__construct($options);
        echo "Creating SUV";
    }
}

carFactory::build('Suv', ['wheels' => 5]);
echo PHP_EOL;
carFactory::build('Sedan', ['wheels' => 4]);

/**
array(1) {
  ["wheels"]=>
  int(5)
}
Creating SUV
array(1) {
  ["wheels"]=>
  int(4)
}
Creating Sedan
**/
```

Comment: Вместо массива лучше использовать класс имплементирующий интерфейс

Comment: а тогда какой смысл конструктора в `carFactory`

Answer (score 1):

Приведу еще пример для случая, когда в конструктор продукта фабрики необходимо передать произвольное число аргументов, при этом разные продукты могут иметь различную сигнатуру конструктора.
Например, если появится класс по типу `car_Sedan_With_Custom_Engine`, с конструктором:

```
class car_Sedan_With_Custom_Engine extends car_Sedan {

    /**
    * @var EngineInterface
    */
    private $engine;

    public function __construct(array $options = [], EngineInterface $engine = null) {
        parent::__construct($options);
        if ($engine) {
            $this->engine = $engine;
        }
    }

    //...методы классы

}
```

Где в конструктор также передается объект, который имплементирует `EngineInterface` (например, для применения паттерна *Strategy*). Тогда можно воспользоваться механизмом отражений `Reflection API` (такой подход нельзя рекоммендовать на все случаи жизни, у него есть определенные drawbacks, но для ряда прикладных задач он подходит) и использовать метод `ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs`. Тогда можно переписать метод фабрики, таким образом:

```
public static function build ($type = '', $args = []) {

    if($type == '') {
        throw new Exception('Invalid Car Type.');
    } else {
        $className = 'car_'.ucfirst($type);
        if(class_exists($className)) {
            $reflect = new ReflectionClass($class);
            $object = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
            return $object;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Car type not found.');
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда клиентский код для создания экземпляра `car_Sedan` примет следующий вид:

```
$sedan = carFactory::build('car_Sedan', [$options]);
```

А для создания `car_Sedan_With_Custom_Engine` :

```
$customizedSedan = carFactory::build(
     'car_Sedan_With_Custom_Engine', [$options, new CustomEngine()]
);
```